# "Cannot import the following key file" error when build outlook add-in project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsto, outlook-addin, app-certification-kit

> Error Message: Cannot import the following key file: . The key file may be password protected. To correct this, try to import the certificate again or import the certificate manually into the current user’s personal certificate store.

Some said to use following command to fix it, though mine doesn't return a container name, so I am not sure how to run this command. We don't have a password in the certificate at all.

`sn -i companyname.pfx VS_KEY_3E185446540E7F7A`